# Convert multipage PDF to PNG with transparency

Tags: pdf, png, transparency, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert

in the moment i run into several problems by converting a PDF file to PNG.
The transparence is lost from the source pdf file.

I have tested the following terminal tools to create the png:
GhostScript, Imagemagick and pdf tools from poppler-tools, always on a debian system.

The image should have the same dimension as the pdf, also the same transparency.

used commands:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=test%d.png -r96 -q design.pdf  -c quit
convert design.pdf test%d.png
convert design.pdf -channel rgba -alpha on PNG32:test%d.png
convert -background none -colorspace srgb design.pdf -colorspace srgb -channel rgba -alpha on PNG32:test%d.png
pdftoppm -png file.pdf test
```

The result is not the expected png with transparency. The Background is white, should be 100% transparent. Additionaly there is a green bar and should be semi-transparent. In all my tries the result ends up in a lighter green box with no transparency.

To see my result, i have uploaded the source pdf, faulty created png and the expected result (export from photoshop).

```
PDF: http://speedy.sh/W75HP/source-file.pdf
Result: http://speedy.sh/hfZMt/faulty-created-design.png
Expected: http://speedy.sh/7mpEk/design-the-way-it-should-be.png
```

I managed to get the white background to be transparent, but the actual file transparency including the semi-transparent green bar/box is not converted properly.

Whats the solution for my issue?

Best regards,
Chris

//UPDATE
Okay we have found a solution with another 3th party tool which produces my expected result on a easy way.

```
inkscape design.pdf -z --export-dpi=100 --export-png=design.png
```

Thx for help

Comment: *The Background is white, should be 100% transparent.* - The background of a PDF page is white according to the specification. Maybe your tools respect the specification and paint the backdrop white first.

Comment: @mkl: No, by default the PDF page background is not white. It will *appear* white by default. But you can change most readers to show it as a chessboard like pattern ***IF*** it is transparent. For Adobe Reader: make sure the checkbox is enabled at *Preferences... -> Page Display -> Page Content and Information -> Show Transparency Grid*

Comment: @KurtPfeifle "The notion of current page is generalized to refer to a transparency group consisting of the entire stack of objects placed on the page, composited with a backdrop that is pure white and fully opaque." ... "The backdrop is nominally white, although varying according to the actual properties of the medium. However, some conforming readers may choose to provide a different backdrop, such as a checker board or grid to aid in visualizing the effects of transparency in the artwork." Thus, it *is* white, but it may be *visualized* differently.

Comment: @mkl: I still do not agree with you. Your quote is from the chapter "Overview of Transparency" inside the official PDF-1.7 specification document.

Comment: Well, if the chapter on *transparency* indicates that the page back drop is at least nominally white and fully opaque, I.e. not transparent at all, it's difficult to imagine that an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

Using Imagick (PHP Extension) I converted a background color into transparent with some code like this (I converted a JPG with white background into transparent PNG):

```
$mask = new Imagick('/your/file/path.jpg');
$mask->setImageFormat('png');
$mask->paintTransparentImage('white', 0, 1000); // $fuzz = 1000 (3rd parameter) is just a guess
```

Take a look here:
http://de3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.painttransparentimage.php

Corresponding Imagick documentation:
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#transparent

Regards,
Michael